# Cant install visual studio 2017 localdb

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb, local-database

I installed ***`Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`***

with its installer i checked the *`Data Storage and processing`*

And ***`Sql Server Express 2016`*** from Individual components

So i can have access to LocalDb in my `C#` app but when `installer/modifer` finishes it gives a error :

**`Setup completed with warnings -> Couldn't install sqllocaldb`**

In log files i found :

```
Package 'sqllocaldb,version=15.1.61710.120,chip=x64,language=en-US' failed to install.
```

.

```
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error
 The error code is 2349. Copy resumed with different info.
```

full log :

```
Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

    1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
    2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
    3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'sqllocaldb,version=15.1.61710.120,chip=x64,language=en-US' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=sqllocaldb;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2349
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\sqllocaldb,version=15.1.61710.120,chip=x64,language=en-US\SqlLocalDB.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS="YES"  SKIPPENDINGREBOOTCHECK="1" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
        Message Id: 2349
        Message Details: The installer has encountered an unexpected error. The error code is 2349. Copy resumed with different info.
    Log
        C:\Users\Disco4uf\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180221144406_003_sqllocaldb.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.27102.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.27102.0)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.27102.0)
        Python development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python,version=15.0.27019.1)
    Impacted components
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26606.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Azure Storage Emulator (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.Emulator,version=15.0.26823.1)
        Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.0.27019.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26621.2)
        Redgate ReadyRoll Core (Component.Redgate.ReadyRoll,version=1.14.17.5347)
        Redgate SQL Prompt Core (Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=8.2.5.2924)
        Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.4.2.1439)
        Snapshot Debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.Snapshot,version=15.0.27102.0)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26906.1)
        SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime,version=15.0.26919.1)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Forget about this

**UPDATE 2**

I got LocalDb Installer to work but when i try to add ServiceBased Database to my app it says missing packages ? (Data sources for SQL Server support)

Comment: Have you tried installing [SQLLocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it after 3 hours !

- Exit visual studio
- Unistall visual studio
- Unistall All "LocalDb"s from `program and features in windows 10`
- Unistall SSDT
- Reinstall Visual studio
- Install SSDT
- Install `Localdb.msi`
- Open visual studio
- Create new winform app
- You now can have service based database (localdb) !